# Remove query param from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, query-string

I have the following URL:

```
http://my.site/?code=74e30ef2-109c-4b75-b8d6-89bdce1aa860
```

And I want to redirect to:

```
http://my.site#/homepage
```

I do that with:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

...

dispatch(push('/homepage'))
```

But react takes me to:

```
http://my.site/?code=74e30ef2-109c-4b75-b8d6-89bdce1aa860#/homepage
```

How can I tell React to drop the query param in the browser's address bar **without reloading the application**?

Comment: What is `push(...)` ?

Comment: @Titus https://decembersoft.com/posts/changing-react-route-programmatically-with-redux-saga/ https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v3/docs/Location.md

Comment: @abelito I see, so it is just the Redux way of calling `this.props.history.push(...)`

Comment: @Titus I am not sure, but it is coming from `react-router-redux`

Comment: ```can please use push({
pathname:'/',
search: '',
hash:'#/hompage'
})
```

Comment: can you try using `history.push(/homepage)` ? with history coming from the route props https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

Comment: @NeelPatel nope, the query param resists all attempts of elimination

Comment: You should not use react-router-redux. It is not maintained. Its last update was a year ago. You should use connected-react-router. I have no such problem with it.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé, nope even using the history directly does not work. And anyway that would probably break redux.

Answer (score 1):

With Regular Expression maybe this solution is easier for you:

```
  var oldURL = 'http://my.site/?code=74e30ef2-109c-4b75-b8d6-89bdce1aa860'
  var newURL = /(http(s?).+)(\?.+)/.exec(oldDomain)[1] + 'homepage'
```

You can use newURL in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (hardcode way)

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

...
const url = `${window.location.origin}/homepage`;
dispatch(push(url));
```

Or this one

```
history.location.pathname =`${window.location.origin}/homepage`;
```

Those methods are not a good practice at all but those work (the second one for sure)

[Read more](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dc10832d23f9ab673891805c9c866b90d1ef1ed6/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

Comment: The first version does not work (query params remain in the URL). The second seems to force a page reload, which is not what I need: the query param is evaluated from the url and stored in the app state, and reloading the page makes me lose the information. To be clear: I want to change the url without forcing a page reload. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Per the following links, I git cloned this and ran npm install in both the main directory and the example basic directory, and ran npm start to get a working example.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/tree/master/examples/basic

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward

Code to remove query params (close to the bottom) and validate that they're removed:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import * as reducers from './reducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...reducers,
  routing: routerReducer
})

const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push("/?test=ok"));
// store2.dispatch(push(history.createHref("/")));
var count = 0;

history.listen(location => {
    console.log(location);
    if (count > 1) { return; }
    count++;
    store.dispatch(push({ pathname:'/', search: '' })); // Drops the params
});
```

Check console and you'll see the query params (search) field is empty

Comment: Not working for me. The internal URL used by react might be changing alright, but the URL on the browser bar remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

See my router section

```
 <div>
                <MainHeader />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/:pickupLocationName/:pickupDate/:pickupTime/:returnDate/:returnTime' render={(props) => <Quote  {...props} />} />
                    <Route path='/BookerInitial/:user/:id' component={BookerInitial} />
                    <Route path='/VehicleList' component={VehicleList} />
                    <Route path='/AdditionalCoverages' component={AdditionalCoverages} />
                    <Route path='/BookingDetails' component={BookingDetails} />
                    <Route path='/RenterInfo' component={RenterInfo} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
```

## There is next buton in BookerInitial page

```
<button className="submit btn-skew-r btn-effect" id="nextBtn" style={{ backgroundColor: "#da1c36" }} onClick={this.handleSubmit}  >Next</button>
```

## Submit button method

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
      this.props.history.push('./VehicleList');

    }
```

I also faced this problem. finally i found the solution
i changed as  this.props.history.push('/VehicleList');
from  this.props.history.push('./VehicleList');
above you can see the dot(.) is the issue with my code. so no need to remove parameter in URL by code.
thank you